# How can i attribute a value by unpacking a tuple?

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

i have a tuple with car names that i want to extract and call them one by one by car_1, car_2, ..., car_n. Let's say i have this tuple:

```
nomes_carros = ('Jetta Variant', 'Passat', 'Crossfox', 'DS5')
```

i want to attribute these values:

```
car_1 = 'Jetta Variant'
car_2 = 'Passat'
car_3 = 'Crossfox'
car_4 = 'DS5'
```

instead of typing one by one, can i do it using for loop or any other function? the only way i know is going by this:

```
car_1, car_2, car_3, car_4 = nomes_carros
```

my real list has about 60 names so it'd be endless to call them one by one. thanks for your help and sorry for my english, did my best

Comment: use a dictionary

Comment: or a list maybe my_list=list(nomes_carros) based on need.

Answer (score 0):

So here is an option with using dictionaries:

```py
cars = ('Jetta Variant', 'Passat', 'Crossfox', 'DS5')
car_dict = {}

for index, car in enumerate(cars):
    car_dict[f'car_{index + 1}'] = car

print(car_dict)
```

also here is this not suggested option but it works by directly adding those variables (not very practical):

```py
cars = ('Jetta Variant', 'Passat', 'Crossfox', 'DS5')

add_to = '\n'

for index, car in enumerate(cars):
    add_to += f'car_{index} = "{car}"\n'

with open('for_so.py', 'a') as file:
    file.write(add_to)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested: you'll want to use a dictionary to solve this problem. For some extra Python points consider using a dictionary comprehension to generate your output:

```py
cars = ('Jetta Variant', 'Passat', 'Crossfox', 'DS5')
{f'car_{i}': car for i, car in enumerate(cars)}
```

If you want to number your cars from `1`, instead of `0`, simply replace `f'car_{i}'` with `f'car_{i+1}'`